# Exporting mongodb 'db' to another node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use the `mongodb MongoClient` to connect to the database once and then use the `db` variable in other places throughout the app. I'm following the pattern offered in [the documents](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling). But for some reason my `db` variable is coming up `undefined`. Here's my code:

in `mongo.js`:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
  MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var dbconnection;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/smartmonthly", function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("connection err ", err);
    throw err;
  } else {
    console.log("successfully connected to the database");
    this.dbconnection = db;
  }
});

module.exports.dbconnection = dbconnection;
```

In `Question.js`:

```
var mongo = require('./mongo.js');

module.exports = {
  all: function() {

     var questionsCursor = mongo.dbconnection.collection('Question').find({"Vertical": "Cellular"} );
     questionsCursor.toArray(function(err, documents) {
        console.log("documents length ", documents.length);
        questions = documents;
        mongo.db.close();
        return questions;
  });
 }
}
```

This code throws an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined` in this line:

```
var questionsCursor = mongo.dbconnection.collection('Question').find({"Vertical": "Cellular"} );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you should do dbconnection = db; instead of this.dbconnection = db;

Comment: I tried that but it produces the same error.

Comment: because module.exports.dbconnection = dbconnection; is executed before the callback, that's why the exported dbconnection is undefined

Comment: A solution : module.exports.getConnection = function() { return dbconnection; }, then in Question.js you can do mongo.getConnection().collection...

Comment: Thanks @oliv37, this works but now the "all" function in Question.js returns before the database operation completes, so I get an empty array sent back vie the http. How do I get it to wait and actually return the question objects that comes back from the database?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: because you need to get the result in a callback (it's asynchronous) -> mongo.dbconnection.collection('Question').find({"Vertical": "Cellular"}, callback);

Answer (score 2):

`dbconnection` can't be export when defined in callback function. if you want to reuse `mongodb connneciton instance` ,you could export a function use promise from native mongodb driver(more information view [offical node monogodb driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/)):

> db.js

```
`use strict';
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
function getDb() {
    return MongoClient.connect(yourConnString).then(function (db) {
        return db;
    })
}

module.exports = getDb();
```

> example.js

```
'use strict';
 var getDbIns = require('./db');
 getDbIns.then(function (db) {
 var col = db.collection("tmp");
 return col.insertOne({name: 'test'}).then(function (res) {
      console.log(res.insertedCount);
      db.close();
      return res.insertedCount;
    })
});
```